# Maximize the LP in a standard LP and minimize it in a canonical form.

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, linear-programming

Maximize the following LP in a standard LP and minimize it in a canonical form.
$$\text{min}\;\;\; z=-2x_1+x_2+5x_3$$
$$\text{s.t.}\;\;\; x_1+x_2-3x_3 \le 6$$
$$2x_1+3x_2-5x_3=7$$
$$-2x_1+x_2+5x_3 \ge -3$$
$$x_1 \le 0,x_3 \ge 0$$

---

I think the linear programming can be maximized in a standard LP like this:
$$-\text{max}\;\;\; z=-2y-x_2-5x_3$$
$$\text{s.t.}\;\;\; -y+x_2-3x_3 +x_4= 6$$
$$-2y+3x_2-5x_3=7$$
$$2y+x_2+5x_3 -x_5= -3$$
$$y,x_3,x_4,x_5 \ge 0$$

And its minimization in a canonical form is:

$$\text{min}\;\;\; z=2y+x_2+5x_3$$
$$\text{s.t.}\;\;\; y-x_2+3x_3 \ge -6$$
$$-2y+3x_2-5x_3 \ge 7$$
$$2y-3x_2+5x_3 \ge -7$$
$$2y+x_2+5x_3 \ge -3$$
$$y,x_3 \ge 0$$

---

I would like to know how much of my work is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there.

According to the convention presented in  Michel Goeman's [note](https://math.mit.edu/%7Egoemans/18310S15/lpnotes310.pdf), we require all the variables to be nonnegative, hence we have to do a transformation to handle $x_2=x_2^+-x_2^-$ where $x_2^+, x_2^- \ge 0$.

Comment: @ Siong Thye Goh, Can you explain my errors? Why do we require to rewrite $x_2$ as $x_{2}^{+}-x_{2}^{-}$ while $x_2$ is a free variable and hence ranges over $\mathbb R$, If you meant to rewrite $x_1$ (which is non-positive) as $x_{1}^{+}-x_{1}^{-}$ then why can't I just transform it to $-y$ with $y \ge 0$?

Comment: are we using the same definition? I think all variables have to be nonnegative right? hence we have to get rid of the free variables.

Comment: So for the first one we have $$-\text{max}\;\;\; z=-2y-x_{2}^{+}+x_{2}^{-}-5x_3$$
$$\text{s.t.}\;\;\; -y+x_{2}^{+}-x_{2}^{-}-3x_3 +x_4= 6$$
$$-2y+3x_{2}^{+}-3x_{2}^{-}-5x_3=7$$
$$2y+x_{2}^{+}-x_{2}^{-}+5x_3 -x_5= -3$$
$$x_{2}^{+},x_{2}^{-},y,x_3,x_4,x_5 \ge 0$$

And for the second one:

$$\text{min}\;\;\; z=2y+x_{2}^{+}-x_{2}^{-}+5x_3$$
$$\text{s.t.}\;\;\; y-x_{2}^{+}+x_{2}^{-}+3x_3 \ge -6$$
$$-2y+3x_{2}^{+}-3x_{2}^{-}-5x_3 \ge 7$$
$$2y-3x_{2}^{+}+3x_{2}^{-}+5x_3 \ge -7$$
$$2y+x_{2}^{+}-x_{2}^{-}+5x_3 \ge -3$$
$$x_{2}^{+},x_{2}^{-},y,x_3 \ge 0$$

Comment: yup, that is correct. btw, for canonical form, can you check your note if your convention is $\le$ or $\ge$.

Comment: Do you mean the convention for the variables?

Comment: For canonical form, is it $Ax \ge b$ or $Ax \le b$?

Comment: It depends, if we want to convert to canonical form and we want to have minimization then we have $Ax \ge b$ but if we want  to convert to canonical form and we want to have maximization then we have $Ax \le b$

Comment: @ Siong Thye Goh, Finally is my last solution correct or not?

Comment: yup, they look fine.